# Accessing form1 textbox from form2 button click

Tags: visual-c++

I have 2 Windows Forms.

In first, the main window form, has multiline textbox and a button. The button opens the second form in which I can add data to array by using AddEntry object.

In second form I have textboxes and a button (btnAddEntry) which should update the content of the textbox from first form.

When data is entered I want to display data in textbox from the first form.

The problem is that code I came up with doesn't seem to work.

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual C# it can be done as follows:

In your secondForm, put the below given lines.

```
private firstForm form_obj;
private void form2_Button_Click()
{
    textBox1.Text = form_obj.textBox1.Text;
}
```

That means, create an object of the form from which you want the values to be grabbed. Then take the value using that object and id of the form field.
:)